# rstudio - is it possible to run a code in the background

Tags: r, rstudio

Question regarding RStudio. Suppose I am running a code in the console:

```
> code1()
```

assume that `code1()` prints nothing on the console, but `code1()` above takes an hour to complete. I want to work on something else while I wait for `code1()`. is it possible? Is there a function like `runInBackground` which I can use as follows

```
> runInBackground(code1())
> code2()
```

The alternatives are running two RStudios or writing a batch file that uses `Rscript` to run `code1()`, but I wanted to know if there is something easier that I can do without leaving the RStudio console. I tried to browse through R's help documentation but didn't come up with anything (or may be I didn't use the proper keywords).

Comment: This is not possible. R is single-threaded. Run two separate R processes instead.

Comment: Also, please don't conflate RStudio with R. RStudio is simply an IDE. RStudio launches an instance of R itself, which is what is actually running your code.

Comment: Which means that running a batch file should succeed.

Comment: @Thomas That R is single threaded doesn't make it not possible to do.  It just means that the hypothetical `runinBackground` function would fork a new separate R thread while leaving the "main" thread unencumbered to continue to tinker.

Answer (score 29):

The [future package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) (I'm the author) provides this:

```
library("future")
plan(multisession)

future(code1())
code2()
```

FYI, if you use

```
plan(cluster, workers = c("n1", "n3", "remote.server.org"))
```

then the future expression is resolved on one of those machines.  Using

```
plan(future.BatchJobs::batchjobs_slurm)
```

will cause it to be resolved via a Slurm job scheduler queue.

This question is closely related to [Run asynchronous function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057849/run-asynchronous-function-in-r/42630770)

Comment: this is only on linux ? or we can run on Windows

Comment: Any operating system

Comment: i'm running API call using the future. But, I don't get the status code. Is there a way I can get the status code after future has been run ?

Answer (score 12):

You can always do this, which is not ideal but works for most purposes:

```
shell(cmd = 'Rscript.exe some_script.R', wait=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 11):

RStudio as of version 1.2 provides this feature. To run a script in the background select "Start Job" in the "Jobs" panel. You also have the option of copying the background job result into the working environment.

Answer (score 8):

The mcparallel() function in the [parallel](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) package will do the trick, if you are on Linux, that is ...

```
library(parallel)
Job1 = mcparallel(code1())
JobResult1 = mccollect(Job1)
```

Comment: This is great - is there any way to print to console from the second task to notify the user when it's finished?

Comment: @BenJones You could simply wrap your code into a function that prints to screen: `wrapper <- function(){ code1(); print("done") }; Job1 <- mcparallel(wrapper()); JobResult1 = mccollect(Job1)`