# Is there a way to run R code in the background while continue to work in the same session?

Tags: r

I want to know if there is a way to run R code (train, mutate, search, ...) in the background, without the need to wait for execution to end or to manually transfer related data to a new session.

Comment: https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/03/14/rstudio-1-2-jobs/

Comment: Possible duplicates - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596786/rstudio-is-it-possible-to-run-a-code-in-the-background or even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057849/run-asynchronous-function-in-r/42630770

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tabs in R-Studio or running multiple sessions in a Jupyer notebook from localhost:8888, localhost:8889, localhost:8890, localhost:8891, etc. is another crude way.

Be mindful of system compute strengths/limitations.